# Logging an HREF without escaped "less than" in java

Tags: java, html, logging

We are using selenium test triggered on a jenkins. As the attachment plugin for junit is for some reasons not working, I'd like to add html-references to screenshots of the test in the log.

The ways I tried to are:

```
logger.info("<a href=\"file:///" + screenshotFile.getAbsolutePath() + "\">Screenshot<a>");

System.out.println("<a href=\"file:///" + screenshotFile.getAbsolutePath() + "\">Screenshot<a>");

System.err.println("<a href=\"file:///" + screenshotFile.getAbsolutePath() + "\">Screenshot<a>");
```

In anyway in the output the

`<` is always escaped as `&lt;`

Comment: How are you viewing the output? `println` does no escaping.

Comment: < has a special meaning and that's why it is escaped as &lt;

Comment: Target is the log-page wihtin Jenkins. But I also checked the output files in the file system..

Comment: The real problem seems to be the surefire-report. This is the tool that creates the output for the jenkins and does the escaping. Still I havent found out how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is commonly occurring problem, try to wrap the string with pre element.

```
<pre>
 //your string
</pre>
```