# Avoid escaping html in logs

Tags: java, logging, escaping

My question is basically the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616679/logging-an-href-without-escaped-less-than-in-java), which has only (not accepted) answer, that I tried and didn't help me, my hyperlinks keep being escaped.

Is there any other solution besides wrapping them in `<pre>` tags?

Comment: which logging framework are you using?

Comment: Commons Logging, 1.1.1

Comment: I tried with commons logging. I got "<" instead of &lt; Can you provide a small hello world example which I can try?